# NullPointerException when calling RingTonePreference on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am getting the following message when calling RingTonePreference on Samsung Galaxy (everything works fine on other phones):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.a
ndroid.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:85
8)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity.onPrepareListView(RingtonePic
kerActivity.java:252)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertCont
roller.java:909)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.ja
va:824)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertActivity.setupAlert(AlertActivity.java:73)
at com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity.onCreate(RingtonePickerActivi
ty.java:226)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

**UPDATE**: Here is how it is called :

```
 <RingtonePreference android:key="pref_notification_ringTone"
                android:title="@string/pref_notification_Ringtone"
                android:ringtoneType="notification" android:showDefault="true"
                android:showSilent="false" />
```

PS : I know the a similar question has already been asked, but no answer was given (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428768/notification-or-alarm-sound-picker-crash-on-galaxy-s/5872352#5872352)

Comment: Are you doing anything in onPrepareListView in RingtonePickerActivity?

Comment: No, I just added the following : <RingtonePreference
         android:key="pref_notification_ringTone"
         android:title="@string/pref_notification_Ringtone"
         android:ringtoneType="notification"
   android:showDefault="true"
   android:showSilent="false" />

Comment: You aren't specifically references RingtonePickerActivity anywhere?

Comment: I updated the description to add how it is called

Comment: Fixed by setting showSilent to true

Comment: @frdroid Post it as an answer and accept you own answer (preferably with some description by it fixed it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was resolved by setting "showSilent=true" in the  definition and is apparently a bug specific to the Galaxy S.

Comment: This is what I did, but I forget to put the answer on the site. Anyway thanks very much for your answer.