# RingtonePreference NullPointerException on LG p990

Tags: android, preferences

I have an error report on Google Play from one of my user. He says, that the application crashes when he tries to select a ringtone for alarm clock, in the moment he clicks on the ringtone in the list. This bug is only on LG p990 and only from one user for now. Any other devices work fine.

Stack from Google Play:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.preference.RingtonePreference.onPrepareRingtonePickerIntent(RingtonePreference.java:225)
at android.preference.RingtonePreference.showRingtonePicker(RingtonePreference.java:184)
at android.preference.RingtonePreference.access$000(RingtonePreference.java:56)
at android.preference.RingtonePreference$1.onClick(RingtonePreference.java:174)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1814)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code from preferences.xml:

```
<RingtonePreference
            android:key="alarm_ringtone"
            android:ringtoneType="alarm"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:showSilent="true"
            android:title="@string/alarm_ringtone" />
```

That user says, that he has updated the firmware, but the result are the same. Some applications crash too when he selects a ringtone for them, but others don't.

Comment: Can you add a bit more code about what your code is trying to do which is causing an error. I would suggest adding those lines of code here which you feel are producing the error. Also please elaborate on what all you have tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have not any more code. It is just PreferenceActivity, which use preferences.xml. No code for processing any events from RingtonePreference. All work is on Android. I read preferences only in AlarmAlertActivity, but it is all right in this activity. As my attempt to resolve this issue I have added this string: 'android:showSilent="true"` as in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874372/nullpointerexception-when-calling-ringtonepreference-on-samsung-galaxy-s)